# Trying to create a classic actor from inside of a akka typed application

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have an akka actor that is using the classic style based on this TCP connection example: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/io-tcp.html

I am trying to instantiate this actor from inside of a akka typed application (because I can't find an example of this exact same TCP connection using typed - not sure if the API is available?)

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem(SomeActor(), "typed-actorSystem")   // import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem

val remote = new InetSocketAddress(config.host, config.port)

val client =
    system.classicSystem.actorOf(Client.props(remote), "clientActor")
```

Error:

> ) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot create top-level
> actor [clientActor] from the outside on ActorSystem with custom user
> guardian [error] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot
> create top-level actor [clientActor] from the outside on ActorSystem
> with custom user guardian

How can I fix this?  Do I have to instantiate this actor somewhere else?

Comment: That actor system seems to be from the classic api. What is SomeActor()?. A classic Akka Actor?, Akka Typed understands Behaviors.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez SomeActor is a akka-typed, my app is akka typed just the Client actor is classic using the TCP connection that I linked too....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are hitting an impedance mismatch between Akka Classic and Akka Typed.

The general recommendation in the Akka docs for this type of situation is to [use a Classic ActorSystem when needing to coexist with classic code](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/coexisting.html#classic-to-typed).  The docs don't spell it out explicitly, but you can then spawn your typed guardian actor's behavior and have all typed actors be a child of that guardian actor, so instead of

```scala
// typed: guardianBehavior is a Behavior[T], so system is an ActorSystem[T]
val system = ActorSystem(guardianBehavior, "my-actor-system")
```

you'd have

```
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter.ClassicActorSystemOps

// A classic actor system
val system = ActorSystem("my-actor-system")

// Typed guardian, will be in the parental chain of all typed actors
val typedGuardian = system.spawn(guardianBehavior, "typed-guardian")
```

This does preclude your typed actors from sending messages to the guardian via `context.system.unsafeUpcast`; other than that, the only operations on `ActorSystem[T]` for which `T` is meaningful are ones that are using it as an `ActorRef[T]`, so those can still use `typedGuardian`, you just have to manually thread it through (which is arguably a more reputable thing than doing `context.system.unsafeUpcast`...)

Comment: thanks!!  curious before with my typed actor system I was doing: `implicit val executionContext = system.executionContext` , how could I get the execution context now?

Comment: The classic equivalent would be `system.dispatcher`