# How do I make a client http request inside of a akka typed actor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

It seems that the http client request API is for classic actors only:

```scala
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
    
   responseFuture
     .onComplete {
       case Success(res) => println(res)
       case Failure(_)   => sys.error("something wrong")
     }
```

I have a akka typed actor and not sure how to make external http requests to my API.

When I added the above inside of my typed actor, I got this error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ClassicActorSystemProvider

What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typed actor system can be easily converted to a classical one and used to send your http request via `akka-http`.

For example, if there is a val of type `akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem`, you can convert it to a classical one in following way

```scala
val system: akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem[_] = ???
implicit val classic = system.classicSystem
```

So now, any method requiring `implicit actorSystem: akka.actor.ActorSystem` method parameter will work.

And from within a typed actor, you can get reference to a context and then to typed actor system, which then converted to classical one

```scala
val behavior = Behaviors.setup[Int] { ctx =>
  implicit val classic = ctx.system.classicSystem
  ???
}
```

Comment: Note that if running in a Typed application with a Typed ActorSystem that isn't `Behaviors.empty`, you may need to restructure the application to use a classic `ActorSystem`, along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658402/trying-to-create-a-classic-actor-from-inside-of-a-akka-typed-application